# Is it possible to turn an already initialized variable into a void*?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, void-pointers

This is a question about the language limitations, please don't answer "you should not do this", it's irrelevant whether you *should* or not, what matters is whether you *can*.

Assume we want to write a subroutine that acquires ownership of ANY object, we could write this, for example:

```
void function(void* object)
{
   // store the pointer somewhere
}

auto ptr = new MyObject(params);
function(ptr);
```

The above works, but forces the user to initialize the objects he desires to store with the `new` operator. I want to know if you can "steal" the contents of the object even if it was initialized normally.

I am wondering if you can do something of the sort:

```
template <typename T>
void function(T& object)
{
   void* ptr = malloc(sizeof(T));
   *ptr = std::move(object); // Or somehting like this
   // store ptr somewhere
}

MyObject object(params);
function(object);
// object variable is now invalid
```

Comment: You may be looking for `new(ptr) T(std::move(object));` See also: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you need to solve? Why do you need to do something like this? And if you want ownership semantics, why not use one of the smart pointers (like `std::unique_ptr`) to begin with?

Comment: Placement new will let you create an object in already-allocated memory. But here you may as well just say `void *ptr = new T(std:::move(object));` Of course the real trick is getting the T back out safely.

Comment: @rustyx std:: any can't store moveable only types

Comment: @Mat can;t do moveable only types

Answer (score 1):

> Assume we want to write a subroutine that acquires ownership of ANY object.

That certainly is not possible with pointer to void alone, because ownership means being responsible for the deletion of the dynamic object, and it is not possible to delete an object through a void pointer.

It could be achieved by using a deleter function object. There is no need to write a wrapper class for that since the standard library has you covered<sup>1</sup>.

> I am wondering if you can do something of the sort:
>
> ```
> void* ptr = malloc(sizeof(T));
> *ptr = std::move(object);
> ```

Not quite this, because you cannot indirect through pointer to void, and besides, you haven't created an object there in the first place, so there is nothing to assign.

It is also a bad idea to move from an lvalue reference argument.

What you appear to be trying to do is to create a dynamic object that is a copy (by move) of the argument object. Here is an example of how to do that:

```
template <typename T>
void function(T&& object)
{
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<T>(std::move(object));
```

You can get a pointer to void like this:

```
void* void_ptr = ptr.get();
```

---

<sup>1</sup> To type-erase an object of any type (as can be achievend with pointer to void), but also be able to own the object (unlike pointer to void), there is a type for that in standard library: `std::any`.

Comment: "and it is not possible to delete an object through a void pointer."
Free(void *);

If custom de-allocation is necessary, request an additional parameter that is a function that deletes the object.

Comment: @Makogan You wanted to be able to have ownership of **any** object. For any non-trivially-destuctible type, `std::free`  is not sufficient.

Comment: std::any cannot contain movable only types

Comment: you are correct, that is why I described a mechanism for those cases where free is not enough. Because it is 100% true that some times won;t be handled correctly by free

Comment: @Makogan Which is also what I said in the answer: You need a destruction function in addition to the pointer to void. Sure, you may be able to optimise it away for special cases that don't need it. There is no need to use `malloc` nor `free` though.

Comment: @Makogan I suppose that if you need move only types, then you could implement a custom version of `std::any` without copy constructor.

Comment: That's more or less what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Makogan. Take a look at any implementation from your favorite choice of standard library implementation or boost, and do the same except for the copying parts

Comment: Instead of rewriting `std::any`, just wrap `T` inside a `MoveOnCopy<T>` class whose copy constructor uses the move constructor.

Comment: @RaymondChen That sounds like something that would invite accidental moving. Seems like a bad idea to me.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can move from a thing that wasn't dynamically allocated, and you can move into a thing that *is* dynamically allocated.

This is only useful, though, if "move" is meaningful and of value for your type. Otherwise you're stuck copying data.

Remember: `std::move` doesn't actually move objects in the sense of transferring or altering their lifetime; it just allows the compiler to pick constructor and assignment operator overloads that *may* perform cheap transfer of some indirect state, to avoid the cost of a deep copy.